Is it common to say "His hair was buzzed real short"?
I found this sentence while reading the book "Let's Get Invisible" by R.L Stine:

His black hair was buzzed real short
on the left side. The rest of it was long, brushed straight to the right.

I searched the meaning of buzzed cut:
" A buzz cut is hairstyle in which the hair is cut very close to the head."
However, the author of the book emphasized that the hair was real short. I think he wanted to emphasize the shortness of the hair. I wonder if this way of emphasizing the shortness is common or unusual? (since the word "buzzed" alone conveys that the hair is very short).

It's very normal.

real short is used for emphasis to say his hair is very short. Spot on.
Hair in a buzz cut is already very short. The emphasis might imply that his hair was recently cut ('buzzed') or mean that his hair is shorter than the speaker would expect for a typical buzz cut.
In spoken English it is common to extend or slow down the 'e' sound in 'real' for further emphasis.

His black hair was buzzed reeeal short on the left side


Note that 'real adjective' (real short, real big, real fast, etc) is mainly used in American English.

In AmE "real" can modify gradable adjectives and then it means "very" or "extremely". We can say "very true" and "really true" but not "real true".

Yes, it is something heard from English speakers.
'Short' describes lots of hairstyles/haircuts that involve cutting hair on different parts of the head to different (but still "short") lengths. An example of this is a crew cut, where the hair on the top of the head is cut relatively short and the sides and back are shorter, sometimes graduated down with clippers.
However, 'buzzed' colloquially means the hair has been cut with clippers at one length all over. Together, "buzzed short" aptly describes a head shaved with clippers to an even length. This kind of style is often called a buzz cut, or sometimes a wiffle cut.
